# javascript not getting correct image width and height

Tags: javascript, html

I have added multiple image upload to my site using HTML api's. I have to test each images while uploading, whether they tall (height>width) or long(height

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function filesProcess(files) 
{
  var shape=document.getElementById('shapeval').value;
  for( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
    {
        file = files[i];
        if(!file.type.match(/image.*/)) 
            {


            alert('File name '+file.name+' is not allowed! Please try again!');

            window.location.reload(true);

                continue; //Jump forward to the next file...

                }
      else
        { 
                var iw=document.images[i].width;
            var ih=document.images[i].height;
            var n=document.images[i].name;
            if(shape="tall")
                {

                    alert("width:"+iw+" and height:"+ih);
                }
                else
                {

                    alert("width:"+iw+" and height:"+ih);
                }
            continue;
        }

    }


}
 </script>
```

HTML

```
  <form action="upload.php/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadForm" onsubmit="return(validate());">
  <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple  onchange="filesProcess(this.files);" accept="image/*"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="shapeval" id="shapeval" value="tall" />
  </form>
```

Using this code width and height are displaying, but the value of them are not correct. Most of the time it's showing 182 and 51 for both type of images; So I couldn't recognize the images are tall or long? Where I did mistake? Am I missing something?Anyone have any idea??

Thanks!

Comment: you are alerting the same thing weather or not the "shape" is "tall".  What are you actually trying to do in that if/else statement?

Comment: value of tall or long is actually coming from database. Here I have just edited that.

Comment: Why are you trying to access the images via `document.images`? The images are in the `files` object you pass to the function, not in the document. And if you do a `console.log()` on your files object, you'll notice that the dimensions aren't there - I don't believe javascript can access this information for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't get the height or width of an image you are about to upload thru Javascript. You will need to upload it to the server and then use PHP (or any other server-side scripting language) to get information about the image. Try the PHP function `getimagesize()`, it should give you the information you need.

If you're wanting to process the image inline and kick back information to the user, I would suggest submitting the form with AJAX and using the response data.

Comment: I am actually uploading all images to server. But I need to make sure that whether the image is long or tall. Tall or long field coming from data base. If the database value is tall, i don't want to upload long images. That's why I need to check the width and height!